# xgboost using single GPU failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, gpu, xgboost

System info:

Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27)

cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130

xgboost: 0.81

python: 3.5.3

The code example:

```
gbm_param_grid = {'learning_rate': [.01, .05, .075, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.75, 1],
                  'n_estimators': np.arange(10, 160, 10),
                  'subsample': [0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1],
                  'max_depth': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                  'min_child_weight': np.arange(0.1, 5, 0.1),
                  'gamma': [i/10.0 for i in range(0,5)]                  
                  }


# 3 things: 1. extra parameters 2. weights on positives 3. new CVs

gbm = xgb.XGBClassifier(objective='binary:logistic', tree_method='gpu_hist')
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
X_test, y_test = X, y
fit_dict = {"eval_set":[(X_test, y_test)],
          "early_stopping_rounds":5,
          "eval_metric":"logloss","verbose":5}

grid_result = GridSearchCV(estimator=gbm, param_grid=gbm_param_grid, fit_params=fit_dict, scoring='roc_auc', cv=skf.split(X, y))
grid_result.fit(X, y)
```

Error message:

```
xgboost.core.XGBoostError: b'[06:06:57] /workspace/src/tree/updater_gpu_hist.cu:908: Exception in gpu_hist: [06:06:57] /workspace/src/tree/../common/device_helpers.cuh:854: Check failed: device_ordinals.size() == 1 (0 vs. 1) XGBoost must be compiled with NCCL to use more than one GPU.\n\nStack trace returned 10 entries:\n[bt] (0)
```

I don't understand why xgboost supposes I am using multiple-gpu?

============================================================

The xgboost module is installed by `pip3 install xgboost`. From the document I suppose this is the correct way to install single-GPU supported version, right?

Comment: Update: seems to be version compatibility issue with the latest CUDA.

Comment: did you ever get this figured out?